# Is Isubscriber (server side plugins) supported in azure devops 2020?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are using server side plugins for automatically creating and updating work items. if we upgrade to server 2020 will the plugins work ?

Comment: Please provide more details to get better understanding. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there are server side plugins in TFS where you can directly use TFS object model and use to automate different aspects of TFS like using REST api, they are isubscriber plugin. The question was regarding that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked \Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins, plugin should be supported in azure devops server 2020. You can try to rebuild your plugin using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.dll from Azure DevOps Server 2020.

[image]

Here is a [ticket](https://vsf-prod.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/972659/plugin-for-azure-devops-2019-onprem-with-isubscrib.html) you can refer to.

Comment: This looks promising i will check this out. I will mark this answer as of now and will confirm later once we check it properly after the upgrade also.